# Print pages of a same report in different tray

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

My requirement is: I have a report with 2 pages. I want to print 1st page of the report in Tray 1 of a printer and want to print the 2nd page of the same report in tray 2 of the same printer.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

This will require a print driver capable of doing that.

So select "Destinations", then "Properties" and select the proper options in the dialog.

[image: Setting printer options]

The XPS driver does not fit the need!

Comment: Thanks Jan. Can you eloborate more.